# having trouble with session_start()

Tags: php, html

I have a login page, home page and a nav page that I include in both of them. The nav shows an admin tab if the session variable admin is a 1. For some reason when I put the session_start on my home page, it shows the admin tab even if someone isn't logged in. The login page works fine. When you aren't logged in it doesn't show the admin tab, but when you log in it does. If i put session_start at the top of the login page instead of in the if statement, it has the same problem as my home page. Am I putting session_start in the wrong place in my home page? I can't figure out why it is doing this. If anyone has some input it would help a lot.

this is part of my login page:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['password'] == $row['password']) { // set session variables and display
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["fname"] = $row['fname'];
    $_SESSION["lname"] = $row['lname'];
    $_SESSION["email"] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION["password"] = $row['password'];
    $_SESSION["admin"] = $row['admin'];
}  else {
    $error= "Password is incorrect";
}// end the if that checks for 1 success
} else {
    $error= "Email not found"; 
}
} //end of overall if
?>
```

this is my nav page:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Products</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="playstation.php">Playstation 4</a>
            <a href="xbox.php">Xbox One</a>
            <a href="switch.php">Nintendo Switch</a>
            <a href="disc.html">Disc Cleaning</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Members</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="addCustomer.php">Create Account</a>
            <a href="editCustomer.php">Edit Account</a>
            <a href="login.php">Login</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Contact Us</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            <a href="feedback.html">Give Feedback</a>
            <a href="feedback.txt">Read Feedback</a>
        </div>
        <?php
            if($_SESSION["admin"] == 1) {
                echo "<li class='dropdown'>";
                echo "<a href='#' class='dropbtn'>Manage</a>";
                echo "<div class='dropdown-content'>";
                echo  "<a href='addProduct.php'>Add Product</a>";
                echo  "<a href='editProduct.php'>Edit Product</a>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</li>";
            }
        ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is part of my home page:

```
<?php session_start(): ?>
<body onload="startRotation()">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
        </header>

        <nav>  
            <?php include "nav.php"; ?>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You have to give `session_start()` as the first thing. Try and let us know.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but shouldn't you put `session_start();` inside your nav page as well? Or perhaps you should echo out `$_SESSION["admin"]` just to be sure what the value is?

Comment: The login page has more `else` than `if`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar It doesn't have to be the first thing, it just has to be before any output.

Comment: there are more closing brackets than needed and it's always better to use `elseif` instead of using two `else` statements.

Comment: Use `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see what session variables are set. I suspect the problem is you're not clearing out session variables when they logout.

Comment: You shouldn't store passwords in the clear in your database. Look up the proper way to do password validation in PHP.

Comment: `session_start():` that is an error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good eye! Didn't even notice that :P

Comment: @icecub first thing that popped out at me.

Comment: I'm voting this as a typo.

Comment: Close this as typo!

Comment: @JeanPaul98 Please don't fix errors in the code when editing a question. Code indention is fine, but people might miss the issues with the question if you start fixing it.

Comment: give your SHIFT key a slight tap ;-) it's stuck

Comment: @icecub I didn't even realized I fixed something, if I did, my bad but thank you for letting me know for next time.

Comment: @JeanPaul98 You've deleted unnessesary closing brackets

Comment: I put it back to how it was

Comment: @JeanPaul98 Good. Seems like I can't change my vote to accept the edit though. Ah well, the question will be closed soon anyway

Comment: Sorry for asking a problem with a typo everyone. Thank you for helping me, though. I overlooked that typo for a while now. It is working now.

Comment: this question should be deleted, it won't serve anyone.

Comment: It won't let me delete it since people have answered, but if there is another way to delete it that you know of let me know so I can.

Answer (score -2):

1.keep `session_start()` be the first thing on your code.
2.It should be in every page you passing the session data.
3.`session_start:` should be `session_start();` on your homepage.

Comment: please, it's been voted as a typo and also addressed in comments.